# How do I remove multiple bracket within nested bracket using sed?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, nested

I want to make a program editing file code with shell programming

there is command **'Remove ${} in arithmetic expansion$(())'**
and I have a problem in implementation.

I'm going to make bash shell code below

> **cnt=$(( ${cnt} + ${cnt123} ))**

to

> **cnt=$(( cnt + cnt123 ))**

**I want to remove command substitution bracket in arithmetic Expansion bracket**

I tried to do with this regex expression:

`sed -Ei 's/(\$\(\()([^\)]*?)\$\{([^\}]+?)\}(.*?)(\)\))/\1\2\3\4\5/g' $file`

but, it just found a longest one.(even though there are another match before matched one)

if you want to see visualized regex expression, click this link [visualized image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBNMt.png)

result showed like this:

> cnt=$(( ${cnt} + cnt123 ))

How to do remove internal bracket in nested bracket?
(I should just use awk or sed, but if it could be impossible, it doesn't matter using other bash command)

---

**works example:**

`s=$(( ${s} ** 2 ))`
to
`s=$(( s ** 2 ))`

`sum=$(( ${a} + ${b} ))`
to
`sum=$(( a + b ))`

`echo $(( (${var} * ${var2}) / ${var3} ))`
to
`echo $(( (var * var2) / var3 ))`

`echo ${d} $((${t1} + ${t2})) ${e}`
to
`echo ${d} $(( t1 + t2 )) ${e}`

---

:my sample input file (it doesn't matter what it do for)

```html
#! /bin/bash

cnt=0
cnt123=1
for filename in *
do
        fname=$(basename $filename)
        cname=$(echo $fname | tr A-Z a-z)
        if [ "$fname" !=  "$cname" ] 
        then
                if [ -e "$cname" ]
                then 
                   echo "$cname already exists"
                   exit 1
                fi
                echo "$fname is renamed $cname"
                mv $fname $cname
                cnt=$(( ${cnt}+ ${cnt123} ))
        fi
done
echo "Total count: $cnt"
exit 0
```

Comment: For `How to do remove internal bracket in nested bracket? (I should just use awk or sed)` please do add few samples for that also so that answers could be tested on those kind of samples too, cheers.

Comment: Find a proper parser and use it instead. This is not a job for sed or awk

Comment: @oguzismail then, What do you recommend to use command for parsing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is not an easy task for sed/awk regex and relevant functions,
please let me show a `perl` solution, although `perl` is not tagged in
your question.

```
perl -i -pe 's/(?<=\$\(\().+?(?=\)\))/ $_ = $&; s#\$\{(.+?)}#$1#g; $_ /ge' "$file"
```

Input file example:

```
s=$(( ${s} ** 2 ))
sum=$(( ${a} + ${b} ))
echo $(( (${var} * ${var2}) / ${var3} ))
echo ${d} $((${t1} + ${t2})) ${e}
```

Modified result:

```
s=$(( s ** 2 ))
sum=$(( a + b ))
echo $(( (var * var2) / var3 ))
echo ${d} $((t1 + t2)) ${e}
```

- The perl substitution `s/pattern/expression/e` replaces the matched
  `pattern` with the perl `expression` instead of literal (or fixed)
  replacement. You can perform a dynamic replacement with this mechanism.
- `(?<=\$\(\().+?(?=\))` matches a substring which is preceded by `$((`
  and followed `))`. Then the matched substring will be the content within
  `$(( .. ))`. The perl variable `$&` is assigned to it.
- The expression `$_ = $&; s#\$\{(.+?)}#$1#g; $_` is a perl code to remove
  the paired `${` and `}` from the matched substring above. The `g` option
  after the delimiter `#` works as that of `sed`.

Comment: Interesting approach! @SeungYunBaek An extended idea for catching nested parentheses, to use a [recursive regex](https://regex101.com/r/Ewr0HX/1) like [this demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##RYpBCoMwFESvMpBP87@hhG6V4h3cGltUgi6ESrNMc/ZodeFmmDdvhj7MOftx/kBT7BOY4nDkmERwTWfX@GH13wX31UMH67h9CXeF4brkupGTpDBOLOiNJ@hWIShHLu7XFDsjSdFDTdVf28nrnDc)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a question for you. you used Perl for solving the problem. but  it looks like different expression. I'm not good at syntax and I saw Perl for the first time , so I might have a misdirection. Why they have difference each other using same regex expression? there's a kind of different version of regex?
.

Comment: @bobblebubble Thank you for your proposal! It might be worked for my question.

Comment: @SeungYunBaek thank you for the response. There are some `regex` variants called `flavors`.
The typical ones are `BRE` (basic regular expressions), `ERE`
(extended regular expressions) and `PCRE` (Perl compatible regular expressions)
in historical order. While `sed` and `awk` supports up to `ERE`,
`Perl`, `python` and other modern languages support `PCRE` which has more
functionalilies such as lookaround assertions, recursive regex and verbs.

Comment: For instance, `(?<=\$\(\()` is a lookbehind assertion which matches leading
`$((` but the matched substring is not included in the capture groups.
It is useful to extract the essential substring only excluding leading/trailing
subpatterns.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -Ei.bak 's/\$\{([^}]*)}/\1/g' input_file
cnt=$(( cnt + cnt123 ))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to remove '$' character too and preserve another '{ }' bracket in the shell code

Comment: @백승윤 Sorry, I missed that, please check edit

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context you may want to limit the extent of the match to only alphanumeric chars

```
sed -Ei.bak 's/\$\{([[:alnum:]]+)\}/\1/g'
```

to avoid unintentionally matching something else.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to remove command expansion in arithmetic expansion, not everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf="cnt=\$(( \${cnt} + \${cnt123} ))" | tr -d '{' | tr -d '}'
```

I used printf here because it is slightly more trustworthy than echo.  Make sure you escape `$`, otherwise you will get an error because of bash trying to interpret the variables.